# JSON Parsing in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I am having problem parsing JSON in my `model.class` I am creating an android app that will request for the user to input the username and password and after clicking the button it will now send a POST request and the request will response with a JSON data.

Here is my request in android studio:

```
//StudentInfo or Login
    client.post("<url here>", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            try{
                    StudentModel sm = new StudentModel(obj);
                    sm.retrievalData();
                    flag = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    navigatetoProfileActivity();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is my StudentModel.class

```
public void retrievalData(){
//some code to parse the JSON



}
```

Well, I am a beginner in json parsing and here is the JSON Response.

```
{
  "info": {
     "add": "<data>",
     "firstName": "<data>",
     "lastName": "<data>",
     "middleName": "<data>",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you can do in `retrievalData()` is:

```
String add = <JSONobjectVariableName>.getJSONObject("info").getString("add");
String firstName = <JSONobjectVariableName>.getJSONObject("info").getString("firstName");
```

and so on.

Comment: I think you meant `getJsonObject("info")`?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the most common way of parsing JSONs to Objects in Java is the following:

```
String json; //the response

Gson gson = new Gson();
Student s = gson.fromJson(json, Student.class);
```

You need to add dependency of Google/Gson. The above will work in case the JSON you receive in the response is a representation of your Student class.

Comment: What specifically is Gson? But I already parsed the JSON using the code above. Thanks for the tips, this might be helpful if I ever encounter GSON.

Comment: Gson is the most popular Java JSON parsing library. It has multiple static methods which let you easily parse an Object to a JSON and vise versa.